# No errors but map is not showing in website in js only background part is visible ,

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

after tried a lot , I had apply previous answer but not got proper solution . Actually I want that when user enter address of location then my code must show that address on map in web . But it is not happening .

**convert.js** :-

```
geocoder=new google.maps.Geocoder();
function getCoordinates(address,callback)
{
    var coordinates;
    geocoder.geocode({address:address},function(results,status){
        alert('Called');
        coordsx=results[0].geometry.location;
        //coords1=results[0].geometry.location;
        coordinates=[coordsx.lat(),coordsx.lng()];
        callback(coordinates);
        //alert(coordinates)
    })

}
```

**testmap.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
    <style>
      #map-canvas {
        width: 700px;
        height: 600px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        left: 360px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="convert.js"></script>
    <script>
    google.maps.visualRefresh=true;
      function initialize() {
      var mapOptions;
      getCoordinates('J-24 MIG colony indore',function(coords){
      mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0],coords[1]),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       } 
       //map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
      alert('Func')
      alert(mapOptions.center);
      });
       map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas" height="100%" width="100%%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you getting your co-ordinates correctly?

Comment: yes i got coordinates correctly

Answer (score 0):

The line `map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);` needs to be inside the anonymous function `function(coords){..` where `mapOptions` is defined. This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
    <style>
      #map-canvas {
        width: 700px;
        height: 600px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        left: 360px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="convert.js"></script>
    <script>
    google.maps.visualRefresh=true;
      function initialize() {
      var mapOptions;
      getCoordinates('J-24 MIG colony indore',function(coords){
      mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0],coords[1]),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       } 
      map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
      });


      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas" height="100%" width="100%%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you had not put map object so it happens try to put these in your code ,

```
map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
```

It will surely work